# Open connection to existing SqliteDB within PHP destructor

Tags: php, sqlite

Why I cannot open connection to my existing sqlite file with php object destructor?

Below is how I use my class Build:

```
  $obj = new Builder();
  $obj -> Initialize($_POST['job']);
  $obj -> Run();
  $obj -> StoreState();
```

In the upper example the function `StoreState()` successfully opens and stores some data into sqlite db.
But if I put that function in `Builder::__destructor()`, then it fails with message "... not such table ..."

Is there any reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try absolute path. The working directory might be different. From [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

> Note: Destructors called during the script shutdown have HTTP headers
>   already sent. The working directory in the script shutdown phase can
>   be different with some SAPIs (e.g. Apache).